# How to apply javaagent to gretty plugin based on gradle command line?

Tags: gradle

The question is specific, but it's more of a general 'how to do this in gradle' question.

I have a demo java web app that I can run using the gretty plugin. I would like to selectively control whether a javaagent is applied to the jvmArgs of the gretty process based on a command line flag.  The agent jar location is known by getting its path from a dummy configuration:

```
configurations {
    agent
}
dependencies {
   ...
    agent group: 'com.foo', name: 'foo-agent', version: '1.0'
}
```

I know I can access the jar file location using something like:

```
project.configurations.agent.find { it.name.startsWith("foo-agent") }
```

How can I selectively apply that to the gretty jvmArgs configuration based on a command line property such as

```
gradle -PenableAgent
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by creating a task and simply calling it before I run the war:

```
task agent {
    doFirst {
        def agentJar = project.configurations.agent.find { it.name.startsWith("foo-agent") }
        gretty.jvmArgs << "-javaagent:" + agentJar 
    }
}
```

Then I can simply call:

```
gradle agent appRunWar
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use Spring Instrument as java agent so this was my solution.
You can make appRun  task dependent on agent task then no additional gradle run parameter needed.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    agent 'org.springframework:spring-instrument:4.2.4.RELEASE'
}

configurations {
    dev
    agent
}
gretty {
    ...
    contextPath = '/'
    jvmArgs=[]
    springBoot = true
    ...
}
task agent {
    doFirst {
        def agentJar = project.configurations.agent.find{it.name.contains("spring-instrument") }
        gretty.jvmArgs << "-javaagent:" + agentJar
    }
}
project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks.appRun.dependsOn agent
}
```